# In Flex 4.5, how can you use getStyleDeclaration on a style in a custom CSS namespace?

Tags: css, apache-flex, namespaces

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. There's some custom namespaces in my Flex project, as well as the usual namespaces like "mx" and "s".

I'd like to use getStyleDeclaration on a style that's in a custom namespace, and I can't seem to figure out the proper syntax.

My stylesheet looks partially like this:

```
.WidgetTitle
{
    fontWeight: bold;
}

myNamespace|ScaleBar
{
    right: 10;
    bottom: 20;
    left: NaN;
    top: NaN;
}
```

If I try to use getStyleDeclaration on ".WidgetTitle", it works fine:

```
trace(styleManager.getStyleDeclaration(".WidgetTitle")); // output: [object CSSStyleDeclaration]
```

If I try the same thing with a custom namespace, it outputs null:

```
trace(styleManager.getStyleDeclaration("myNamespace|ScaleBar")); // output: null
```

I've tried all the combinations I can think of: "myNamespace|ScaleBar", "myNamespace.ScaleBar", "myNamespace ScaleBar" etc and I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: This is just a guess -- I used to be on the Flash Builder team and I implemented the IDE's support for this CSS-namespace stuff.  (I'm no longer at Adobe.)  Try "myNamespace::ScaleBar" or "myNamespace:ScaleBar".  I vaguely remember that one of those might work.  I'm just posting this as a comment because there's a good chance I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Button in myComps package:

```
package myComps
{
    import spark.components.Button;

    public class MyButton extends Button
    {

    }
}
```

In application class:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace myComps "myComps.*";

    myComps|MyButton{
        color: #ff0000;
        fontSize: 30;
    }
</fx:Style>
```

and

```
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    private function _creationCompleteHandler():void
    {
        var css:CSSStyleDeclaration = styleManager.getStyleDeclaration("myComps.MyButton");
        trace("fontSize", css.getStyle("fontSize"));
        trace("color", css.getStyle("color"));
    }
]]></fx:Script>
```

trace:

```
[trace] fontSize 30
[trace] color 16711680
```

For me it works.

Comment: This works!  I just had to enter the fully-qualified class name in dot notation (which is what you've done here) and it all worked. Accepted your answer. Thanks!